# Flutter PopUntil Black Screen Despite Route On Stack

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-navigation

I'm trying to use Navigator.popUntil, but I keep ending up at a blank screen.  I understand that this can happen if the screen that you're popping until is not in the stack, but that is not the case for me; my screen should be in the stack.  I am using named routes, if that makes a difference.

[image] [image]

When the user presses the "No" button, I want to pop the dialog and then the delete screen to get back to the Account Management screen, as shown in the image.

```
          TextButton(
              child: const Text("No"),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.popUntil(
                    context, ModalRoute.withName(AppRoutes.accountManagement));
              }),
```

AppRoutes.accountManagement is defined as:

```
static const accountManagement = '/accountManagement';
```

The ApplicationManagement, AccountManagement, and DeleteAccount pages are pushed onto the stack using the following code:

```
  ///Called to navigate on the main, global navigator
  void _routeNavigation(String route) {
    try {
      Navigator.pushNamed(context, route);
    } catch (e) {
      DebugLog.printToConsole("Exception during navigation: Exception $e");
    }
  }
```

Where each string is defined as follows:

```
  static const appManagement = '/appManagement';
  static const accountManagement = '/accountManagement';
  static const deleteAccount = '/deleteAccount';
```

It seems that the pop is not finding the AppRoutes.accountManagement route on the stack, but I can't see why.  Should these screens be nested?  That is, I see they are all on the same level in the Widget Viewer (as in the image).  What am I doing wrong that is causing popuntil to not be able to recognize a route that is on the stack?

Answer (score 0):

Try popping it like this

```
Navigator.of(context).popUntil((route) => route.settings.name == "${AppRoutes.accountManagement}");
```

Comment: Alas, I tried that, and a few variations of it, and I still got the black screen.

Comment: Try navigator.pop(context); to remove the alert dialog then do this

Comment: Still no luck. :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Navigator.of(context).pop();
Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {
  Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, '/accountManagement', (_) => false);
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that is resulting in the following error:  "package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart': Failed assertion: line 5139 pos 12: '!_debugLocked': is not true."  This is because I want the account management screen to remain on the stack, and I don't want to remove the items under it on the stack.  In other words, I want to be able to navigate away from the account management page after performing this operation.